# Generate random inputs using a fuzzer

Tags: python, fuzzing, random-data

Let me take a very small example of what I am looking for.

def add_two_numbers(x, y):
return x + y

I want to input n number of times, the random values for x and y.

Is there any python fuzzing library that I can use for generating such values (integers, strings, alphanumeric, etc.)

If you guys can suggest a few python libraries that can be used for to generate random data (fuzzing).

Comment: The `random` library?

Comment: The `random` library is a built-in library so you don't even need to install it https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: Could you give some details on the context.
On your `add_number()` example do you want to fuzz all kinds of user input or just numbers ?

Answer (score -1):

Random is a library with a bunch of useful features, here's some of the features.

```
import random
num = random.randint(1,100) # generates a random whole number between 1 and 100
print(num)
num = random.random() # generates a random float number less than 1
print(num)
num = random.uniform(1,100) #generates a random float number between 1 and 100
print(num)
num = random.uniform(1,999) #generates a random float number between 1 and 100
num = round(num, 2) #rounds that number to two decimal places
print(num)
```

Comment: Your answer is limited to numbers whereas the question also mentions alphanumeric.

Comment: @0x0fba But their example code is for adding two *numbers*. I'd guess they accepted alphanumeric because they were planning on producing numbers using these.

Comment: @0x0fba random can be used to generate letters too... for example if you just save the letters of the alphabet to numbers and generate an integer, a randomly generated 3 would be 'c'